# Loading XML into a OLE DB Destination Editor using SSIS

Tags: xml, ssis, active-directory

I have an [**SSIS**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx) job that queries [**Active Directory**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742424.aspx) and saves user account records into our database.  It uses a [**Script Component**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137640.aspx) to execute the required LDAP queries, and loads the user account values into variables defined in the [**Output Buffer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223822/assign-value-to-ssis-script-component-new-output-column) which lives in the [**Script Component**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137640.aspx).  Once processed, I take the results from the [**Output Buffer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223822/assign-value-to-ssis-script-component-new-output-column) and use an [**OLE DB Destination Editor**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141237.aspx) to map the values into a table.

Currently, I am loading the XML into a "[**Unicode string [DT_WSTR]**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141036.aspx)" variable, but it has a maximum upper limit of 4000 characters.  As such, I cannot process XML larger than 4000 characters (yet)...but I want to.

I'm still new to SSIS...and I have tried various online examples to no avail.

**How can I parse XML *larger than 4000 characters* into something the [Output Buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223822/assign-value-to-ssis-script-component-new-output-column) can use and the [OLE DB Destination Editor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141237.aspx) understands?**

Comment: You could implement this in a tool that doesn't have this limit, i.e. Powershell, VBScript. Are you simply dumping the XML output into a column in a table or are you shredding it before it goes into a table? This link has a powershell script to load SQL Server with SPN's. Users should just be a different AD query: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3167/get-sql-server-spn-information-for-all-servers-using-powershell/

Comment: All the other fields are easy. The 2 fields I transform into XML are the Manager and DirectReports.  And...Manager will probably not exceed the 4000 character limit.  However, DirectReports is a list of UserAccount nodes which "could" easily exceed the 4000 character limit.